# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)

Tags: xss, url

I was browsing the web and typed in a URL to visit, when I received the following response:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)

I did some research on this error and found that this is associated with cross-site scripting, and began to worry when I discovered that this could be interpreted as someone trying to hack into a website??

I see ampersands in URLs I visit all of the time (I saw many when I just did a Google image search), so I didn't think it anything malicious.

What does this mean for me? Should I be concerned?

Comment: What did the full request URL look like?

Comment: https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/light-from-the-keyhole-picture-id118347397?k=6&m=118347397&s=612x612&w=0&h=Zs7w6nmqqSsEY_56j6xAPwuP5Z6uuwepq-IVoczgcVY=

Comment: While I can't reproduce the error from the link you provided, it just seems to be an overeager WAF which triggers when it encounters a `&` where it doesn't belong. It's most likely a false positive and nothing to worry about.

Comment: That is weird. When I typed it, it took me to the error page. But when I clicked on it, it took me to the (royalty free) photo. I'm afraid to click on the link I provided but that's the one that was typed.

Comment: This malformed URL triggers: https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/light-from-the-keyhole-picture-id118347397&k=6&m=118347397&s=612x612&w=0&h=Zs7w6nmqqSsEY_56j6xAPwuP5Z6uuwepq-IVoczgcVY= (I replaced the `?` with a `&`.)

Comment: Yes, I clicked on your link and that's what happened the first time. It appears I made a mistake when typing it. Does this change your false positive diagnosis?

Comment: No, it's just detecting malformed URLs and treating them as attack attempts. There is no actual attack going on.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got really scared, especially after reading people have gone to jail for typing in single quotation marks (') in places they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to visit a website with a malformed URL in it. A web application firewall (WAF) or similar thought it looked a little bit suspicious, and blocked your request. Apparently, the WAF is not configured veyr well, so it displays error messages to the user, instead of just a 404 page.

Regarding `&` in URL:s, they would normally be seen in the query string (the part after the `?`). There, they are used as separator between different parameters, as in `?color=green&size=medium`. I don't think putting them in a different part of the URL is a sign of any specific attack. But it's not a bad idea to block odd input even if it is not obviously an attack, just to be on the safe side.

So to summarize: Nobody tried to attack you. The webserver mistook a misspelled URL you visited for a potential attack, and blocked it. That's completely normal. You don't need to be worried about anything here.